# Optional default prop for PureComponent in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am  using `react` 16.x and `connect` from `react-redux` and I am trying to set default properties for my component.

```
interface CounterProps {
  incrementAsync(): void;
  increment(): void;
  decrement(): void;
  value?: string & number;
}
class Counter extends React.PureComponent<CounterProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.incrementAsync}>
          Increment after 1 second
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={this.props.increment}>Increment</button>{' '}
        <button onClick={this.props.decrement}>Decrement</button>
        <hr />
        <div>Clicked: {this.props.value} times</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But in te `connect` line I got compile error
`Argument of type 'typeof Counter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{ value: number; } & { incrementAsync: () => void; incre
ment: () => void; decrement...'.`

It seems to be something wrong with type of the props. I have checked and `PureComponent` extends from `Component` which contain `props: Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<P>;` and `ReadOnly` does not allow for optional keys.

Is it even possible to have and set optional props for `PureComponent`'s?

Comment: There is possible to set optional props for `PureComponent`. Do you have any code for the parent component?

Comment: show your full code with using `connect`

Comment: The parent component is irrelevant, `Counter` is independent component. I need to set default props inside `Counter` component.

Answer (score 1):

```
value?: string & number; - typo
```

You need to use or: `value?: string | number;`

If you want to set defaultProps:

```
interface CounterProps {
  incrementAsync(): void;
  increment(): void;
  decrement(): void;
  value?: string & number;
}

class Counter extends ... {
  static defaultProps = {
    value: 0,
  };
  ...
}
```

or Functional Component:

```
export const Counter:FC = ({ value = 0, ...otherProps }) => (
  ...
</div>);
```